# Delphi - disable controls not working EMS Advanced Export 4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I tried to disable ABSQuery1 controls  before exporting data :

```
procedure TForm1.QExport4Dialog1BeforeExportRow(Sender: TQExport4;
  Row: TQExportRow; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
ABSQuery1.DisableControls;
end;
```

But I get :

```
> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(75): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TQExport4'
> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(76): E2003 Undeclared identifier:
> 'TQExportRow' [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(204): E2005 'TQExport4' is not a
> type identifier [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(205): E2005 'TQExportRow' is
> not a type identifier [dcc32 Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(15): F2063
> Could not compile used unit 'Unit1.pas'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error messages all indicate that you have not used the units in which the named symbols are declared. Add those units, those that declare TQExport4 and TQExportRow, to the uses clause of your Unit1.

---

It's usually worth consulting the documentation when you encounter a compiler error that you do not understand. Search for the error code, for example E2003. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2003_Undeclared_identifier_%27%25s%27_%28Delphi%29) says:

> The compiler could not find the given identifier - most likely it has been misspelled either at the point of declaration or the point of use. It might be from another unit that has not mentioned a uses clause.

The final sentence covers your scenario, although the author got in a tangle when writing that text and the words don't make a lot of sense. Sigh.

Incidentally, the example at the bottom of that documentation page made me sad. The author indicates a preference, when correcting mis-named variables, for the option requiring the fewest key strokes. Never mind getting the name right, just make it compile with the fewest key strokes and who cares about the next person to read the code. Pah!

Comment: It had me baffled for a little.... thought the component adds by itself the uses clause but it seems not.